# How to convert binary output to values in relation to a column in r

Tags: r

The sample data is as follows

```
ID <- c(1, 2, 3)
O1D1 <- c(0, 0, 0)
O1D2 <- c(0, 0, 0)
O1D3 <- c(0, 10, 0)
O2D1 <- c(0, 0, 0)
O2D2 <- c(0, 0, 0)
O2D3 <- c(18, 0, 17)
O3D1 <- c(0, 9, 0)
O3D2 <- c(20, 1, 22)
O3D3 <- c(0, 0, 0)

x <- data.frame(ID, O1D1, O1D2, O1D3, O2D1, O2D2, O2D3, O3D1, O3D2, O3D3)
```

I created a new column with some conditional logic.
Say, the new column is `n`

```
x$n <- (x$O1D3 > 0 & x$O2D3 == 0)
> x$n
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

What I am looking to get instead is a column with values such as

```
> x$n
[1] 0 10 0
```

Or, in other words, the values of O1D3 should replace `TRUE` values in the `n` column and the `FALSE` values can be replaced with 0.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: `ifelse(x$O1D3 > 0 & x$O2D3 == 0, x$O1D3, 0)`

Comment: Or just multiply, `with(x, O1D3 * (O1D3 > 0 & O2D3 == 0))#
[1]  0 10  0`

Comment: x <- data.frame(ID, O1D1, O1D2, O1D3, O2D1, O2D2, O2D3, O3D1, O3D2, O3D3) %>% 
  mutate(n = case_when(
    x$O1D3 > 0 & x$O2D3 == 0 ~ 10, 
    TRUE ~ 0
  ))